# Advice to create a code for selectin image

Tags: javascript, html

i would like to create a function (javascript) where some images are displayed on the screen and the user can chose one of them by simply clicking over it. Once chosen, the src of the picture will be stored in a var. So far i made an images array, but i dont know if it's the right way to proceed, do any of you have some tips? Thanks all!

```
 <script typre="text/javascript">
        var img = new Array();
        img[0] = new Image();
        img[0].src = "../images/poggiatesta2.jpg";
        img[1] = new Image();
        img[1].src = "../images/poggiatesta1.JPG";
        for (var i = 0; i < img.length; i++) {

            document.body.appendChild(img[i]);
        };
        </script>
```

Comment: Can you share your code ? How will user deselect the image ?

Comment: The user won't be able to deselect an image, he can just select another one. To make you understand better: it's a program to create a personal relax armchair by selecting every component, that's why a user can't deselect an image.

Comment: Can you share the code ?

Comment: Kindly create a fiddle of the same so that one can work on that...Also do not share your code in comments..Better you edit your question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```js
var img = new Array();
  img[0] = new Image();
  img[0].src = "http://dummyimage.com/200/000/fff&text=Img0";
  img[1] = new Image();
  img[1].src = "http://dummyimage.com/200/000/fff&text=Img1";
  img[2] = new Image();
  img[2].src = "http://dummyimage.com/200/000/fff&text=Img2";
for (var i = 0; i < img.length; i++) {
  var imagetag = document.createElement("img");

  var onclick = document.createAttribute("onclick");
  onclick.value = "myfun("+i+")";
          
  var sorc = document.createAttribute("src");
  sorc.value = img[i].src;
          
  var id = document.createAttribute("id");
  id.value = "my_image"+i;
          
  imagetag.setAttributeNode(onclick);
  imagetag.setAttributeNode(sorc);
  imagetag.setAttributeNode(id);
          
  document.body.appendChild(imagetag);
};

function myfun(i) {
  var src = document.getElementById('my_image'+i).src;
  //you can do anything with 'src' here
  document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = src;    //for demo purpose
}
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: Im gonna try it out! Thanks! :)

Comment: It works perfectly! Thank you very much! I have other few questions: since the var src is local, when i create new pages how can i retrieve it?

Comment: Simply load the same js file to the new page and access `src` from there

Comment: If an answer is correct please accept, so that others can know this is the right answer. Also it is a great way to thank some one for their effort

Comment: Sure, just last question: can i edit the images size with css?

Comment: Create a `class` attribute and add to `imagetag` like `var class= document.createAttribute("class");` , `class.value = "my_img_class";`. Then add to `imagetag` by `imagetag.setAttributeNode(class);`

Comment: Again, thanks for the time you dedicated to me, i really appreciate it!

Comment: Hey, it's still me, i did what you wrote, but how should i name the class in css?